Force on current carrying loop due to non-uniform magnetic field
I was been taught that when there is a non-uniform magnetic field then the Force on a current carrying loop with Magnetic Moment M is F = M(dB/dx) where B is magnetic field.
I can't get hold of this equation.  Can you give an intuition of how this is true (without or without involvement of mathematics).

Can you tell where this equation for F comes from? there should be vectors ?
